# How to Autocomplete in ct-vue-light-bootstrap-dashboard template form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete

How to disable autocomplete in the current form?

```
   <fg-input
                            v-validate="'required|min:3'"
                            data-vv-name="Login"
                            label="Login"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Login"
                            v-model="form.login"
                            autocomplete="none">
                        </fg-input>
                        <span v-show="errors.has('Login')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first("Login") 
    }}</span>

                        <fg-input
                            data-vv-name="Description"
                            label="Description"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Description"
                            v-model="form.description"
                            autocomplete="none">
                        </fg-input>
                        <span v-show="errors.has('Description')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first("Description") }}</span>

                        <fg-input
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            data-vv-name="Password"
                            v-validate="form.id ? '' : 'required|min:3'"
                            v-model="form.password"
                            autocomplete="off">
                        </fg-input>
```

Now it looks  like this:

[image: now it looks like this]

Used template 
https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-vue-light-bootstrap-dashboard-pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add autocomplete="new-password" attribute to your password input and everything will work as you want.
Example

```
                        <fg-input
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            data-vv-name="Password"
                            v-validate="form.id ? '' : 'required|min:3'"
                            v-model="form.password"
                            autocomplete="new-password">
                        </fg-input>
```

hrome no longer supports autocomplete="off"